# Google sheet query display different column

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have 2 sheets that I want to combine, the 1st sheetname "CustInfo" has Column Name

FirstName      LastName       Request

the 2nd sheetname "Reply" has Column Name

FirstName      LastName       Accepted

I want to create a query that has a result like this

FirstName     LastName      Request       Accepted

Can anyone is kind to help.
Thank you in advance, appreciated.

12Rev79

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both sheets has Column D and it is blank:

```
=QUERY({{"FirstName", "LastName", "Request", "Accepted"};
CustInfo!A2:D;
{Reply!A2:B,Reply!D2:D,Reply!C2:C}},"select * where Col1 is not null",1)
```

Comment: Thak you so much @idfurw